# Django Channels Live Chat: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'as_dict'

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I've been following this tutorial to implement a live chat system into my Django project. so far it has gone well and i've fixed any issues which have come up but this one stumped me.

```
2018-02-26 19:45:34,241 - ERROR - worker - Error processing message with consumer TestApp.consumers.ws_receive:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 46, in run
consumer(message)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 57, in inner
return func(message, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blog_dev/TutorsTalk/TestApp/consumers.py", line 23, in ws_receive
Group('chat-'+label).send({'text': json.dumps([m.as_dict()])})
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'as_dict'
```

This error seems to only come up when websocket data is being received which is why when i'm trying to send data it is saved to the database. This means that I can read the messages if I open it on another browser or refresh the page. I can also tell that my disconnect code works too because in the Django development console it is telling me when IPs are disconnecting from the websocket.

As you can probably tell I am quite new to this. This is my code in consumers.py

```
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    label = message.channel_session['room']
    room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
    data = json.loads(message['text'])
    m = room.messages.create(handle=data['handle'], message=data['message'])
    Group('chat-'+label).send({'text': json.dumps([m.as_dict()])})
```

I have tried some things that I thought might work but to no avail. Please tell me if I should provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/1.x/channels/message.py) that the `Message` class does not have `as_dict` method defined in it.

If you want to get the message content, you can access `.content` property of a `Message` instance to get the `Message` content `dict`. (This is mentioned in the `Message` class documentation string)

**Fix**:

```
Group('chat-'+label).send({'text': json.dumps(m.content)})
```

Answer (score 0):

**m** is instance of model So below ways to convert object into dict

```
 1. m.__dict__
    > Group('chat-'+label).send({'text': json.dumps(m.__dict__)})

 2. from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
    model_to_dict(m)
    > Group('chat-'+label).send({'text': json.dumps(model_to_dict(m))})
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow that tutorial to. Paste this lines, on the model Message.

```
@property
def formatted_timestamp(self):
    return self.timestamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

def as_dict(self):
    return {'handle': self.handle, 'message': self.message, 'timestamp': self.formatted_timestamp}
```

and It will work